# Understanding Tuple to List conversion behaviour: list(t) or [*t] which is better?

Tags: python

I've a tuple as below:

```
t=(1,2,3,4,5,6)
```

I want to convert it to a list, although there is a straight forward way of

```
l=list(t)
```

I wanted to understand if the below is more inefficient, if so in what way?

```
l=[*t]
```

This is more to understanding if unpacking and packing it back into a list has any overheads vs `list(tuple)`.

I'll try and benchmark the two and post the results here, but if anybody can throw some insight it would be great.

Comment: Benchmark it and see for yourself.

Comment: May be using timeit?

Comment: `%timeit list(t)` best of 3: 294 ns per loop
`%timeit [*t]` best of 3: 176 ns per loop

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is pretty easy to check yourself with the [timeit](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/timeit.html) and [dis](https://docs.python.org/2/library/dis.html) modules. I slapped together this script:

```
import timeit
import dis

def func(t):
    return list(t)

def unpack(t):
    return [*t]

def func_wrapper():

    t = (1,2,3,4,5,6)
    func(t)

def unpack_wrapper():

    t = (1,2,3,4,5,6)
    unpack(t)

print("Disassembly with function:")
print(dis.dis(func))

print("Dissassembly with unpack:")
print(dis.dis(unpack))

print("Func time:")
print(timeit.timeit(func_wrapper, number=10000))
print("Unpack time:")
print(timeit.timeit(unpack_wrapper, number=10000))
```

And running it shows this output:

```
Disassembly with function:                       
  5           0 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (list)
              2 LOAD_FAST                0 (t)   
              4 CALL_FUNCTION            1       
              6 RETURN_VALUE                     
None                                             
Dissassembly with unpack:                        
  8           0 LOAD_FAST                0 (t)   
              2 BUILD_LIST_UNPACK        1       
              4 RETURN_VALUE                     
None                                             
Func time:                                       
0.002832347317420137                             
Unpack time:                                       
0.0016913349487029865
```

The disassembly shows that the function method's disassembly requires a one additional function call over the unpacking method. The timing results show that, as expected, the overhead of the function call vs using a built-in operator causes a significant increase in execution time.

By execution time alone, unpacking is more "efficient." But remember that execution time is only one part of the equation - this has to be balanced with readability and in some cases, memory consumption (which is harder to benchmark). In most cases, I would recommend you just stick with the function because it's easier to read. I would only switch to the unpacking method if this code is executed frequently (like in a long-running loop) *and* is on the critical path of your script.